# How can I remove the bottom divider like lines in my layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a layout as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerPadding="0dp"
        android:showDividers="none"
    >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
         >
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:editable="false"
                android:text="Bla"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerPadding="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Bla Bla"
                    android:editable="false"
                    />
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Bla Bla Bla"
                    android:editable="false"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

The bottom of the widgets has a rigid line like a separator. How can I remove it? I tried the `android:divider="@null"` etc but still there?

Comment: can you show a `screenshot` of that line so we can understand it better?

Comment: show the screen shot. because may be we use different theme so unble to point out what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set this property on all the `EditTexts`:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: @Jim I don't see the difference :)

Answer (score 1):

They are not the dividers of layouts. They are the default backgrounds for EditText. You should change their background to anything else you want.